# update "public"/"private" status of Asana tasks?

Tags: asana

Can I use the Asana API to change a task from public to private or vice versa?

I've checked in the documentation (http://developer.asana.com/documentation/) and don't see anything there.

Comment: Their API is really new, so it's possible they didn't include everything yet. Try to send them a message over twitter (https://twitter.com/#!/asana), they've always replied to me

Comment: Thanks, asked. If they answer I'll post here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

We also monitor StackOverflow. :) You are correct, changing private/public visibility of tasks is not yet part of the API. Adding this functionality is part of the roadmap, but I can't comment on when it will happen.